# Do i need transactions to get the correct last inserted ID in a sequence?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have one database table called products, i'm trying to insert a product A on the table and return the id of product A after it has been inserted into the table. My php code for doing this is the following:

```
    public function save(Product $product) : int
    {   
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
          "INSERT INTO products VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        );
        $error = ! $stmt->execute([
          $product->name,
          $product->description,
          $product->picturePath,
          $product->userId,
        ]);
        return $error ? -1 : $this->conn->lastInsertId('products.id');   
    }
```

I was thinking about the possible problems i can have with this code and the first question which came to my mind is: If a client makes a request to insert product A into the table and before i get product A's id, another request is made to insert product B, will i get product B's id? yes? If no, why don't?

The second question is: If i use a transaction to insert product A and to retrieve it's id, then will i get product A's id?

Answer (score 2):

You could surround it with a `try` and `catch` and use the PDO [begintransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), [commit](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php), and [rollback](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) functions. Examples can be detailed on [PHP PDO:lastinsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
 try { 
        $conn->beginTransaction(); 
        $stmt = conn->prepare(
          "INSERT INTO products VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        );
        $error = ! $stmt->execute([
          $product->name,
          $product->description,
          $product->picturePath,
          $product->userId,
        ]);
        $id =  $conn->lastInsertId();
        $conn->commit(); 
    } catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
        $conn->rollback(); 
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
    }
```

IMO it's Better to apply good coding practices than to just go on a whim and hope for the best. :)

Comment: I do agree with doing all database operations in transactions and it does really help ensure your database is in a clean state.

Answer (score 1):

The `lastInsertId()` value is maintained per connection, so if there are other connections inserting data into the same table, you don't have to worry about those; your value will be the one for your connection.

If you use a transaction that succeeds and then you roll back, the `lastInsertId()` will still retain its value. Rollback does not affect the current value of `lastInsertId()`.

Comment: Thanks, did you get this information on the mysql docs as well?

Comment: Actually I tried it out and found that rollback did not change the value.

Comment: Ok. I think this should be another question: the PDOStatement::execute docs says that false will be returned if some failure happens, but on the lastInsertedId docs no value is mentioned in case of a failure like broken internet connection, i think i will use try/catch only to handle lastInsertedId failures, and i will use no transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine because in MySQL its tied to the connection and that request should be using the same connection. Other requests might happen at the same time incrementing the highest ID in the table but it should not return those values.

Its explained quite well in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client.

Comment: Thanks, how the connection between the php code and the mysql server works is very interesting to me, i will try to learn more about it.